# Forcing VMWare Workstation Traffic Through Fiddler

Tags: vmware, fiddler

I just installed Windows 8 on a virtual machine using VMWare and I'm trying to use fiddler to capture HTTP Traffic and I'm unable to do so. I have set the network settings to NAT but that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler is an HTTP proxy. You need to use something like WireShark, which will capture traffic at the driver level (technically at the "NIC" level but a VMware virtual adapter isn't a physical device...).

You could point the guest to use your proxy, but it doesn't HAVE to... there's nothing enforcing that all TCP/IP traffic in the guest must go through your Fiddler proxy. The only way to ensure that it happens is to install a netfilt driver (such as the one that comes with Wireshark) which sees every packet that goes through your network driver.

Comment: OK so I install Wireshark and point the traffic to Fiddler using the netfilt driver? Sorry my knowledge regarding these matters is not as good as I like it to be

Comment: No. Install Wireshark and use *it* to analyze the traffic. Don't use Fiddler at all.

Comment: I'm using fiddler's autoresponder to replace a piece of javascript code on a website, can wireshark do the same?

Comment: Oh, OK. So you're trying to actually MODIFY the data with Fiddler. I get it. Ok. So you just need to create a host only networking connection on your guest (perhaps in addition to the usual NAT) and make sure that your Fiddler proxy is listening on the IP Address of the host on the host only network (check ipconfig /all in the terminal). Then you can do a direct connection from the VM's web browser to Fiddler by configuring the proxy settings in the browser. But you will need full control over the guest browser.